# Why mention Achashverosh's pillars?

Tags: megillat-esther, talmud-bavli, tractate-megillah

The *Bavli* spends several pages (*M'gila* 10–16) going through parts of the book of Esther with aggadic commentary.

Esther 1:6 describes a party:

> חוּר כַּרְפַּס וּתְכֵלֶת אָחוּז בְּחַבְלֵי בוּץ וְאַרְגָּמָן עַל גְּלִילֵי כֶסֶף וְעַמּוּדֵי שֵׁשׁ מִטּוֹת זָהָב וָכֶסֶף עַל רִצְפַת בַּהַט וָשֵׁשׁ וְדַר וְסֹחָרֶת

The *Bavli* has this to say about that:

> **חור כרפס ותכלת** מאי **חור** רב אמר חרי חרי ושמואל אמר מילת לבנה הציע להם **כרפס** אמר ר׳ יוסי בר חנינא כרים של פסים **על גלילי כסף ועמודי שש מטות זהב וכסף** תניא ר׳ יהודה אומר הראוי לכסף לכסף הראוי לזהב לזהב אמר לו ר׳ נחמיה א״כ אתה מטיל קנאה בסעודה אלא הם של כסף ורגליהן של זהב **בהט ושש** א״ר אסי אבנים שמתחוטטות על בעליהן וכן הוא אומר אבני נזר מתנוססות על אדמתו **ודר וסוחרת** רב אמר דרי דרי ושמואל אמר אבן טובה יש בכרכי הים ודרה שמה הושיבה באמצע סעודה ומאירה להם כצהרים דבי רבי ישמעאל תנא שקרא דרור לכל בעלי סחורה

As you see, it skips the words "אחוז בחבלי בוץ וארגמן" and "על רצפת" (as it does many other parts of other verses). Yet it sees fit to include "על גלילי כסף ועמודי שש". Why are those five words in the *Bavli*? They don't seem germane to the discussion immediately prior or the one immediately after.

Comment: English translations for pretty much every relevant part of this question would vastly improve its quality

Comment: @JoshK, I agree completely, but wasn't sure how to include a translation of words that the גמרא is interpreting. I'll try בלי נדר, but no time now.